# How to write bigint (timestamp in milliseconds) value as timestamp in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, timestamp, unix-timestamp, milliseconds, bigint

I'm trying to store in timestamp with timezone field my value. It is in milliseconds from 1970.

`select TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(1401432881230), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.MS')`

Expected `30/5/2014 11:29:42 10:54:41.230`, but get
`22/08/46379 23:27:02.000`

Comment: `select TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(1401432881222 / 1000), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') || '.' || (1401432881222%1000)` is good-style query?
Returns `30/05/2014 06:54:41.222`

Comment: `to_timestamp` already considers milliseconds, that's why it accepts floating point unix timestamps. If you want to store a real timestamp, just store what it returns. If you want to format it, use `MS` to display milliseconds.

Comment: But in my example (select TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(1401432881230), 'DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI:SS.MS')) I'm doing as you said.

Answer (score 63):

[Unix timestamps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) measures time with seconds, and **not** milliseconds (*almost* everywhere, in PostgreSQL too).

Therefore you need to call

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(1401432881230 / 1000);
```

If you want to preserve milliseconds, call with `double precision`:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(1401432881230::double precision / 1000);
```

Comment: You can also write `TO_TIMESTAMP(1401432881230 / 1000.0)` instead of the explicit cast, if you want.

Comment: Will using double prevision introduce rounding errors?

Comment: @KamilCuk it can, yes; but there's no `to_timestamp(numeric)` variant [currently](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html), the parameter will anyway be converted to `double precision` whatever one use.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I convert ms to timestamp and keep ms instead seconds.The accepted answer will drop ms.

```
WITH ts AS (SELECT 1401432881230 AS ts)
SELECT to_timestamp(ts / 1000) + ((ts % 1000 ) || ' milliseconds') :: INTERVAL
FROM ts;

-- FOR ALTER COLUMN
ALTER TABLE  my_info
  ALTER COLUMN tstmp TYPE TIMESTAMP USING to_timestamp(tstmp / 1000) + ((tstmp % 1000) || ' milliseconds') :: INTERVAL;
```

Answer (score -2):

Okay, I understood. My INSERT should looks like:

`INSERT INTO events (timestamp) VALUES (to_timestamp(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP(1401432881222 / 1000), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') || '.' || (1401432881222%1000), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS'))`

I'm converting bigint-timestamp with milliseconds to text with required format ('YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.MS') and pass it to to_timestamp function.